# Why are the only numbers $m$ for which $n^{m+1}\equiv n \pmod{m}$ is true also unique for $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{m}{n^m}\equiv 1 \bmod m$?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

It can be seen [here](http://www-groups.dcs.st-and.ac.uk/~john/Zagier/Solution1.1.html) that the only numbers for which $n^{m+1}\equiv n \pmod{m}$ is true are 1, 2, 6, 42, and 1806. Through experimentation, it has been found that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{m}{n^m}\equiv 1 \bmod m$ is true for those numbers, and (as yet unproven) no others. Why is this true?

If there is a simple relation between $n^{m+1} \bmod{m}$ and $n^m \bmod{m}$, that would probably make this problem make more sense. It is obvious that $n^m \equiv 1 \pmod{\frac{m}{d}}$ (dividing out $n$ from both sides gives this result) for all $n$ on the interval $[1,m]$ where $d$ is a divisor of $m$. As a result of this, $n^m \bmod{m}$ takes on only values of the form $1+k \frac{m}{d} \pmod m$ where $k = -1, 0, 1$. How can it be shown that the sum of those values is equivalent to $1 \bmod{m}$?

Comment: Have you checked to see if the other entries of A007018 work?  (Also, the second paragraph doesn't mean much; you are just subtracting 1 from both sides and using the fact that m^m is divisible by m.

Comment: yeah, I only noted it due to the whole odd numbers lead to getting 0 when taken mod m.

and the next entry is 3263442... I don't think I have the computational power to check it :\

Comment: The next entry is 1806.  Does it work?

Comment: 3263442 is wrong, the result of modding is 1807. Similarly, 47058 -> 5797, 3270666 -> 1811.

Comment: The next smallest m satisfying the condition is 1806, which coincides with A007018.  But as KennyTM commented, 3263442 does not satisfy the condition.

Comment: Probably it is [A014117](http://www.research.att.com/~njas/sequences/A014117)?

Comment: @Eugene: Probably you should put the EDIT 2 as answer. (Although I don't see A014117 is a proof that there are at most 4 numbers in your case.)

Comment: Done so below. Should I accept it as well?

Comment: @Eugene: If you think it completely solves the problem, yes. (Although you can't accept it within 24 hours).

Comment: As of yet I'm stuck on relating it to the original problem...

Comment: You claim that the correct sequence is A014117, and you write that you do not know why.  Something is wrong there.

Comment: After running through thousands of numbers those were the only ones that worked... while that's not a proof in itself, the pattern is the same and I'm sure there is some sort of relation. I have not yet found it.

If you would like to help _find_ that relation, that would be much more helpful than simply saying I'm wrong and doing nothing about it.

Comment: Well, n^m mod m takes on a limited amount of numbers on the range [1,m].

For example, for m = 42, all n^m mod m are members of {0,1,7,15,21,22,28,36}.

0 only occurs when n = m, 21 only occurs when n = 21 = m/2. 1 and 22 occur 12 times, which is the same as phi(n) (total of numbers coprime to m less than m, a.k.a. Euler Totient Function). This is interesting because it also applies to m = 1806! of all the values the mod takes on, it takes on 903 (1806/2) exactly once, and takes on 1 and 904 exactly 504 times, which is phi(1806).

Then what do the other numbers mean?

Comment: To clarify, n^m mod m takes on only as many values as there are divisors of m. For each unique value of gcd(n,m), n^m mod m takes on exactly one value. For example:

if gcd(n,m) = 2 (e.g. 2, 4, 8), then n^m mod m = 22
if gcd(n,m) = 7 (e.g. 7, 35), then n^m mod m = 7
etc.

Comment: The current wording of the question states a conjecture as if it were a known fact, which makes it difficult to understand the current situation.  I have been trying to help you improve the wording of the question.  Of course, I would like to help you in another direction, namely prove your conjecture, but the problem is difficult for me and I have not succeeded.  You can keep accusing me of not doing anything useful if you would like to.

Comment: I modified it to be a little more clear... is this better? I added some information that may be more relevant.

Comment: I have an unfinished proof developing here: http://mathbin.net/51297

anything I missed? I feel like I'm almost there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I've made a full proof! Part 1 was solved [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/37097/37155#37155), and Part 2 was solved [here](http://www-groups.dcs.st-and.ac.uk/~john/Zagier/Solution1.1.html).

**Lemma 1:** Any integer $m$ which satisfies the original problem also satisfies $n^{m+1} \equiv n \bmod{m}$ for all $n$.

**Proof:** Let $p$ be a prime dividing $m$. Then $\sum_{n=1}^mn^m\equiv1\pmod p$, so $(m/p)\sum_{n=1}^{p-1}n^m\equiv1\pmod p$, so $p^2$ doesn't divide $m$. Let $g$ be a primitive root mod $p$. Then $\sum_{n=1}^{p-1}n^m\equiv\sum_{r=0}^{p-2}g^{rm}$. That's a geometric series, it sums to $(1-g^{(p-1)m})/(1-g^m)$ which is zero mod $p$ - unless $g^m=1$, in which case it sums to $-1$ mod $p$. So we must have $p-1$ dividing $m$. Looking at  $n^{m+1}\equiv n\pmod m$ and letting $n=p$, we see that $p^2$ cannot divide $m$. Now looking mod $p$, we get $n^{m+1}\equiv n\pmod p$. This is equivalent to $m+1\equiv1\pmod{p-1}$ (if $a^x \equiv a^y \bmod{n}$, then $x \equiv y \bmod{\varphi(n)}$ by Euler's theorem, and $\varphi(p) = p-1$), that is, $p-1$ divides $m$, so any integer $n^{m+1} \equiv n \bmod{m}$ as $p-1|m$ for all $m$ if $p|m$.

**Lemma 2:** There are only a finite amount of integers $m$ which satisfy $n^{m+1} \equiv n \bmod{m}$

**Proof:** Since $p^2$ does not divide $m$, we may let $m = p_1 \ldots p_r$ with $p_1 < p_2 < \ldots < p_r$, with $p_i$ prime; as $p-1|m$ for all $p|m$, we say that $p_i-1|p_1 \ldots p_{i-1}$ for $i = 1, \ldots, r$. If we take $i = 1$, this forces $p_1-1|1$, so if $r \ge 1$, $p_1 = 2$. If $i = 2$, $p_2-1|2$, so if $r \ge 2$, $p_2 = 3$. Continuing, if $r \ge 3$, then $(p_3-1)|p_1 p_2 = 6$, so $p_3 = 7$; if $r \ge 4$, $(p_4 - 1)|p_1 p_2 p_3 = 42$, so $p_4 = 43$, as the numbers $d+1$ are not prime for other divisors $d$ of 42 larger than 6. If $r \ge 5$, then $(p_5 -1)|p_1 p_2 p_3 p_4 = 1806$, but 1, 2, 6 and 42 are the only divisors of 1806 with $d+1$ prime, so $p_5$ cannot exist. Therefore, $r \le 4$ and $m \in \\{1, 2, 6, 42, 1806\\}$.

Comment: I don't see how $n^{m+1} = n \mod m$ follows from $n^{m+1} = n \mod p$. Aren't those theorems etc useful only if $n$ and $m$ (or $p$) are co-prime? Care to explain a bit more?

Comment: If $p$ divides $m$, then two things will be the same $\bmod{m}$ and $\bmod{p}$, I believe. And they work regardless of whether $n$ and $m$ are coprime, especially because $n$ is just a number from 1 to $m$.

Comment: @Eugene: Those theorem are not guaranteed to work if we remove the co-prime condition. Not sure why you think so. Do you have a reference?

Comment: the only reference I really have is the link I added to the proof on mathoverflow. there is a more reliable proof (with bernoulli numbers) but that's a little too advanced, so I prefer this one.

Comment: As for the theorems:

Let $a$, $b$, and $n$ be integers, and let $p$ be a prime dividing $n$. If $a \equiv b \bmod{n}$, then $a = b+j n$ where $j$ is any integer. Because $p|n$, $n = k p$ for some integer $k$, meaning $a = b + j k p$. Since $j k p$ is an integer multiple of $p$, it can be said that $a \equiv b \bmod{p}$.

Comment: The mathoverflow answer is correct. The claim there is that, if m is such that for every prime p which divides m, p^2 does not divide m and p-1 divides m, then m is one of the finite set you have. What you seem to state here (that n^(m+1) = n mod p implies n^(m+1) = n mod m) is completely different and I am not sure it is correct. Also, please give credit to the person who came up with that. From your answer it sounds like you have come up with it yourself.

Comment: If I have misread, I do apologize.

Comment: in the first line I said I made a proof out of it, but I also immediately link to where each part was solved. I'm not taking responsibility for the solution, just the format. the thing is that the problem was originally a question asking to find the sum of all integers such that the sum was equivalent to 1 mod m, so I had to reformat the proof.. that may have led to some incorrect statements. if that is the case I'll correct it, but right now I can't see how to correct it :\